# OneToMany Hibernate Save Cascade Problems

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I was working with Hibernate and OneToMany Relationship, i came across a weird behavior today , ***although i did it purposely but i was not expecting this behavior***

College.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COLLEGE")
public class College implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="COLLEGE_XID")
    private Long collegeId;

    @Column(name="COLLEGE_NAME")
    private String collegeName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="college",cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    //... with get and setters
}
```

Student.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student implements Serializable    {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="STUDENT_XID")
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name="STUDENT_NAME")
    private String studentName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="COLLEGE_XID",nullable=false)
    private College college;
    //... with get and setters
}
```

Application.java

```
    College college1 = new BdCollege();
    college1.setCollegeName("C_1");

    College college2 = new BdCollege();
    college2.setCollegeName("C_2");

    Student student1 = new BdStudent();
    student1.setStudentName("S_1_C_2");

    CollegeDAO collegeDAO = new  CollegeDAO();

    // setting student 1 Parent to College 1        
    student1.setCollege(college1);   // <---- Here the Issue  ... student 1 as college 1 child

    // BUT assigning Student 1 as Child of Collge 2 in List 
    // i did it purposely to test the behaviour
    college2.getStudentList().add(student1);  // <---- Here the Issue ... but assigning it in the list of College 2 ... ws expecting Exception 

     // Saved College 1 & 2
     collegeDAO.save(college1);
     collegeDAO.save(college2);

      // Saved Successfully BUT
```

RESULT
 COLLEGE Table

```
 COLLEGE_XID     COLLEGE_NAME    
 --------------  --------------- 
 1               C_1             
 2               C_2
```

STUDENT Table

```
 STUDENT_XID     STUDENT_NAME     COLLEGE_XID    
 --------------  ---------------  -------------- 
 1               S_1_C_2          1
```

I was expecting some exception as assignment from child and parents mis-matched in college - student example
 and another thing that stucked me were the query generated by hibernate

```
Hibernate: insert into COLLEGE (COLLEGE_NAME) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into COLLEGE (COLLEGE_NAME) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENT (COLLEGE_XID, STUDENT_NAME) values (?, ?)
```

i.e it save College 1 first, Then College 2 Second and Saving Student as Child of College 2 but in the result it appears as child of College 1

Comment: "Saving Student as Child of College 2" How can you be certain of this. You just see SQL without values. It may be saying the student with college_xid as 1 in the first place.

Comment: @shazin Well indeed this is not certain and :) this is not the real problem, for ur comment i have tried with different cases, Hibernate Generates SQL in the order the objects are saved...

Comment: Its because you haven't got any cascades set anywhere. Because you have specified a `@JoinColumn` on your `@ManyToOne` a column exists for Hibernate to create an insert statement around. But because Hibernate doesn't know how to map your student list back to your persistent student object, it can't do anything with it. Just my $0.02

Comment: @JamesMassey @OneToMany(mappedBy="college",cascade = CascadeType.ALL) cascades are mapped in College Class

Comment: Herp derp, missed that. Perhaps Hibernate is taking the join column as precedence to the cascade.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you added mappedBy attribute and made student as owner of association.
Since Student entity is the owner, it will maintain the relationship and hibernate will ignore changes on College side.